# Reading string and numbers from text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

My text file format is something like this:

X  Y

1.2 3.2

1.0 4

0.9 10

I want to grab only the numbers in two columns. So far I have tried load, textread, it gives error with first line of the txt file. How can I ignore the first string line and grab only the numbers in file?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the error message that you're seeing.

Comment: And also code that you use to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) function.

```
A = importdata ('textfile.txt', ' ', 1);
data = A.data
```

The parameters:
'textfile' is the name of the file that contains your data,
' ' is the delimiter,
1 tells the function that there is one header line

With `A.colheaders{1}` and `A.colheaders{2}` you even can access the names of you columns.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `textread`, which has the option `'headerlines'`.  You'd call it like

```
[A,B]=textread('textfile,txt','%f %f','headerlines',1); %this ignores the first line
```